# Is there a common "bad word" list?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm looking for a list of common bad words so that I can create a filter.

Preferably a list with whole words, I don't want to filter out every word that contains a bad word (i.e. filtering all words containing ass would filter "assassinate")

Comment: Glad that you're trying to make the clbuttic mistake.

Comment: "Bad" in what sense? Sexually suggestive? Policitcally incorrect or inflamatory? Vulgar?

Comment: @John - how so? Wouldn't only filtering out whole words eliminate making the clbuttic mistake?

Comment: Depending on the context, you may find it relevant to read the tale of the [long-necked giraffe and fluffy white bunny](http://habitatchronicles.com/2007/03/the-untold-history-of-toontowns-speedchat-or-blockchattm-from-disney-finally-arrives/).

Comment: Steven: Sorry! Meant to say that I'm glad that you're trying *not* to make the clbuttic mistake.  (Oh and ++ by the way)

Comment: http://fffff.at/googles-official-list-of-bad-words/

Comment: This turns into an attractor for "Please create traffic on my content." answers. It also always was off-topic for asking for external content.

Answer (score 6):

I collected 2200 bad words in 12 languages: en, ar, cs, da, de, eo, es, fa, fi, fr, hi, hu, it, ja, ko, nl, no, pl, pt, ru, sv, th, tlh, tr, zh.

MySQL dump, JSON, XML or CSV options are available.

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [No swearing.](http://www.noswearing.com). they presently have a limited api, but you can make a http request directly using their search url.

http://www.noswearing.com/search.php?st=ass&submit=Search